# Unable set background color to List item in Custom CursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

I am trying to give alternate background color to my list view. I am using cursor adapter.
Here is my CustomCursorAdapter class

> CustomCursorAdapter.java

```
public class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_item, parent, false);

    return retView;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    TextView textViewPersonName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_person_name);
    textViewPersonName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(1))));

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    if (position % 2 == 0)
        row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#191919"));
    else
        row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#323232"));
    return row;

}
}
```

In getView(); I have setBackgroundColor to view. but they are not get assigned properly only texview background color are got affected. and here is my single_row_item.xml

> single_row_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/tv_person_name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my output. please tell me how to do this.

[image]

Comment: In your **single_row_item.xml** use one Linear Layout. I mean use one parent Linear Layout.

Comment: + for the Cursor.getPosition()  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the Answer. It was just small silly mistake. In My Activity's XML in which I have list view. That list view should have width = "fill_parent" or "match_parent".

[image: Final output]

Answer (score 0):

**Try moving the logic for setting the colors of alternative rows to `bindView()` method instead of `getView()`.**

In CursorAdapter, you get layout in `newView()` and bind data in `bindView()`. CursorAdapter already do reuse pattern in `getView()` so you don't have to do it again.

The `getView()` for `CursorAdapter` delegates to `newView()` and `bindView()`.
So the `getView()` method uses the view recycling mechanism along with delegating the row construction to the `newView()` and `bindView()` methods.

This means in the case of the `CursorAdapter`, all of that is taken care of for you by implementing `newView()` and `bindView()`.

Comment: I moved this code to bindView() but not solved yet.                              int position = cursor.getPosition();
        if (position % 2 == 0)
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#191919"));
        else
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#323232")); `\

Comment: length of background color got increased. but doesn't fill whole row.